# Trouble elongating div next to another

Tags: css, html

I'm have two `divs` floated next to each other on one line. The first div should have a predefined length and be on the left side, and the second should elongate its length based on window size, div size, etc. on the right side. **Basically two divs on the same line, one small, the other as long as possible to fit the text.**

Here's what I have right now:
http://jsfiddle.net/nkuvW/

But as you can see the `Thing2` is stuck on the other side, and no matter what I've tried, Thing2 will not elongate to thing1.

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
#thing1 {
    margin: 14px 14px 14px 43px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
#thing2 {
    margin: 14px 14px 14px 43px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: Gets you a little closer without the margin: http://jsfiddle.net/Sefje/

Comment: I want a little separation though between each.

Comment: What about: http://jsfiddle.net/vCQxZ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work pretty well:

```
#thing1 {
    padding: 4px;
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
#thing2 {
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

- [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vCQxZ/)

Comment: As this solution is simpler, this is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @lawm -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<div style='position:relative; padding-left:75px; background-color:red;'>
       <div style='position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:75px;background-color:green; border:1px solid black;'>Thing 1</div>
    <div style='border:1px solid black;'>Thing 2</div>
    </div>
```

Also see here: http://jsfiddle.net/S7zbh/5/

Comment: But this doesn't work if I'm styling Thing 2 as a separate entity as well. You removed the borders, which were part of my point.

Comment: Just add another wrapper. Like so. <div id='t2' style...>thing2</div> I will update the js fiddle. Updated. No each thing :) is a thing of its own.

Comment: Hmm.. It doesn't work well with margins though: http://jsfiddle.net/S7zbh/8/ what if I want the two entities separated?

Comment: The thing on the left is positioned absolute. Just change the padding on the container.  Like so : http://jsfiddle.net/S7zbh/9/ , note that the margin (top-bottom) is done by the container- the row)

Comment: Sorry, but the other guy's answer seems to simpler. Thanks anyway!